# Export MS Access tables as dBase 5 through VBA MS_Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

How can I export a single table as a dBase 5 file through VBA?

Currently I am using this VBA code:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
acExport, _
"dBase IV", _
"DB_Total", _
acTable, _
"DB_Total", _
"C:\Data", _
False
```

But when I try to execute this code, I get the following error (in dutch, so roughly translated):

```
"DB_Total is not a valid path"
```

But I'm not really sure what the path is, because the table I am trying to export is inside the Access file, right?

Comment: According to the docs you should need the full path to the output database in the 4th parameter: DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "dBase IV", "c:\full\path\to\output.dbf", acTable, "TableNameInAccess", "Output.dbf", False, False

Comment: This seems to work, but my file gets saved as " C__DATA_.DBF " , Is there any way for me to change that ?

Comment: @DanMetheus you should post your answer, Gutanoth, you must set the proper argument to the name you want, as Dan says, `DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
acExport, _
"dBase IV", _
"C:\Data", _
acTable, _
"DB_Total", _
"DB_Total", _
False`   See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196455.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should need the full path to the output database in the 4th parameter:

```
 DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "dBase IV", "c:\full\path\to\output", acTable, "TableNameInAccess", "DBFTable", False, False
```

Also I believe you will have to limit your output (DBFTable) to 8 or fewer characters because it is dBase IV.