# need to convert CSV file to DBF file from MS-Access 2007 through Macro

Tags: ms-access-2007

I need to convert CSV file to DBF file from MS-Access 2007 through Macro
Please Help me!
I am stuck with it.
I want to automate it,as its a daily need in my firm
I need a button that whenever i click on it,it picks up the CSV file and convert it into DBF file 
I Have the idea,what all i can do but i dont know how to do it.

Comment: Too broad. Voting to close it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. *Access 2007* knows nothing about DBF files.

One option is to get hold of an *Access 2000* copy. Then export your data to an Access 2000 format *mdb* file, and open this in Access 2000 and export as *DBF*.

**Edit**:

This answer claims to work with Access 2007:

[Export MS Access tables as dBase 5 through VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019964/export-ms-access-tables-as-dbase-5-through-vba-ms-access)

Also, I tested that with Access 2000. It doesn't know *dBase 5*, but dBase IV works for me:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "dBase IV", "c:\test", acTable, "TestTable", "DBTable4", False, False
```

Note that *the file name is limited to eight characters*.

Comment: [DoCmd.TransferDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196455%28v=office.14%29.aspx) knows dBase 3 to 5 formats, isn't this DBF?

Comment: Yes, but does it work for you? I tried and receive a 2507 error: "Not installed database type or not supported action."

Comment: Hmm. With Access 2010 I am able to manually export a table via `External Data -> Export -> More -> dBASE File`, but `DoCmd.TransferDatabase` fails both with existing and new target files. <shrug>

Comment: I have only Access 2016 at hand, and here neither does the manual export offer anything exotic like those old formats. A bit strange really, as Visual Studio happily connects to an _Access 2.0_ database.

Comment: Of course not. But Access 2007 seems not to be the tool. Get hold on an old Access 2000, it can do it. See edited answer.